# how to increment with find -exec?

Tags: bash, shell, increment

I Would like to do something like that

```
#!/bin/bash

nb=$(find . -type f -name '*.mp4' | wc -l)
var=0
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec ((var++)) \;
echo $var
```

But it doesn't work ? Can you help me ?

Comment: What's `nb` for? And what command do you want to run? What do you want to achieve overall?

Comment: Do you want to count the number of files found by your `find` command?

Comment: BTW, `find ... -print | wc -l` isn't an accurate count for all possible file names. Try creating a file with `touch $'name\nwith\nfour\nlines'` -- it'll be counted by `wc` as four separate files. That's why you're safer using NUL delimiters (as with `-print0`) -- they can't show up in filenames themselves.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Or you can do something like `-printf '.'` and count the periods.

Comment: Yup. I want to say I've seen `-print0` in some non-GNU `find`s that don't have `-printf`, though. (Actually -- confirmed: MacOS has `-print0` but not `-printf`).

Comment: ok but where should i put printf or print0 ?

Comment: @romainlavisse, as the action for `find`. There's a default action of `-print` in some versions (which your original code is relying on), but it's not good practice to do so (there are cases where that default action will take place when you don't want it to -- that's often the case when a `find` expression includes `-prune`, for example).

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Incrementing a variable (even supposing you could) serves no useful purpose. What do you want to use it for? Renaming files? If so, there is a `rename` command.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Each `exec` is performed in a separate process. Those processes aren't part of your shell, so they can't access or change shell variables. (They could potentially read *environment* variables, but updated versions of those variables would be lost as soon as the processes exited; they couldn't make changes).

If you want to modify shell state, you need to do that *in the shell itself*. Thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh; do not run as "sh scriptname"

while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  ((++var))
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -print0)
```

Note preincrement vs postincrement -- that helps you [avoid some gotchas](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) if you're running your script with `set -e` (though I'd argue that the better practice is to avoid that "feature").

See [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for details.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you require:

```
bash-4.4$ var=$(find . -name "*.mp4" -exec echo {} \;|wc -l)                                                                                                                        
bash-4.4$ echo $var                                                                                                                                                                 
4
```

it counts the number of *.mp4 files inside the dir and assigns the number to var.

Comment: Filenames can have newlines in them -- an ideal answer would avoid double-counting in that case.

Comment: To test this yourself: `touch $'hello\ncruel\nworld.mp4'; echo hello*.mp4 | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

This is using `find` but not with the option `-exec`, if you just want to store in a variable the number of items found, something like this could work:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(find . -type f -name '*.mp4' | wc -l  | awk '{print $1}')

echo $var
```

Comment: Put the single quotes *outside* the curly braces if you want to be sure the braces are passed to `awk` by your shell (which otherwise will be handling them in an implementation-dependent manner which can vary between shells). That is: `'{print $1}'`, not `{'print $1'}`

Comment: the first line in my script already do that. What i want is to know each time i got a ".mp4" i want to increment a count

Answer (score 0):

**short and sweet** with the help of `-c` option in `egrep`

```
ALP ❱ find . | egrep mp4$
./T/How_to_Use_Slang_at_the_Market_English_Lessons.mp4
./T/How_to_Use_Slang_on_the_Road_English_Lessons.mp4
./T/How_to_Use_Slang_on_Vacation_English_Lessons.mp4
./T/How_to_Use_Slang_at_the_Airport_English_Lessons.mp4
./T/How_to_Use_Slang_to_Talk_about_Health_English_Lessons.mp4
./list-mp4
ALP ❱ find . | egrep -c mp4$
6
ALP ❱
```